# Python: RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of %S was never called

Tags: python, pyqt, runtime-error, superclass, deep-copy

I tried to do some operation (`setParent`) on an object in Python (an instance of a class which inherits from a different class - to be specific, `QtGui.QLabel`), but during runtime the above error was raised. The object itself has had some fields with actual content (verified on debug), but from some reason I couldn't "use" it. What does the error mean and how can I fix it? For some additional information, I shall say that the object was returned from a static method before I tried to do this operation on it.

The subclass has a `__init__()` function of its own:

```
def __init__(self, image, father):
        super(AtomicFactory.Image, self).__init__(father)
        self.raw_attributes = image.attributes
        self.attributes = {}
        father.addChild(self)
        self.update()
```

Now I wrote a similar code, a simple one, that had the same error on the line `widget.setParent(mw)` when the window was moved.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import copy
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_widget=QtGui.QWidget()
    widget = QtGui.QPushButton('Test')
    widget.resize(640, 480)
    widget.setParent(main_widget)
    widget.move(0, 0)
    widget2=QtGui.QPushButton('Test2')
    widget2.i=0
    widget2.resize(600, 200)
    widget2.setParent(main_widget)
    widget2.move(640, 0)
    def onResize(event):
        print event
        mw=copy.deepcopy(main_widget)
        widget.setParent(mw)
        widget2.setParent(mw)
        widget.move(0, 0)
        widget2.move(640, 480)
        main_widget_width=main_widget.width()
        widget_width=widget.width()
        width2=main_widget_width-widget_width
        height2=widget2.height()
        widget2.resize(width2, height2)
        widget2.move(640, 0)
    main_widget.resizeEvent=onResize
    def onClick():
        size=(widget2.width(), widget2.height())
        if(widget2.i%2==0):
            widget2.resize(int(size[0]/2), int(size[1]/2))
        else:
            widget2.resize(size[0]*2, size[1]*2)
        widget2.i+=1
    QtCore.QObject.connect(widget, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), onClick)
    main_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What was the problem?

Comment: If your derived class `MyDerived` has its own `__init__` try adding the line `super(MyDerived, self).__init__()`.

Comment: It does. The object was actually created before and was used fine. I could have also used setParent() without problems in the initial stage. It was then inserted into a list and the static method I described above "found" it within the list, and then returned it to another static method. When the latter tried to use setParnet() on it, the error was returned. Anyways, the __init__() custom function of the subclass is:

Comment: def __init__(self, image, father):
            super(AtomicFactory.Image, self).__init__(father)
            self.raw_attributes = image.attributes
            self.attributes = {}
            father.addChild(self)
            self.update()

Comment: I kind-of doubt the static method has anything to do with this, but I might be wrong.

Comment: What is your subclass? Is it `AtomicFactory.Image`, or something else?

Comment: Yes, AtomicFactory.Image is the subclass

Comment: No. It can't be `AtomicFactory.Image`.
In the `super` call you must put the name of that class. If you put the name of a different class, or of an ancestor class you might break things.
Obviously you can't have:
`class AtomicFactory.Image(QLabel, ...): ...`, because `AtomicFactory.Image` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: The class is named `Image`, and it's defined under a class named `AtomicFactory`... That's not the problem, as I said, it did work some of the time.

Comment: In your last sample code I _think_ that the problem is that `copy.deepcopy` will copy the python object, but not the underlying C++ object.
By the way: what does it mean "it's defined under a class named AtomicFactory"? Does it mean that you defined a class inside a class?

Comment: Yes. What do you mean by underlying C++ object?

Comment: When you create a `QObject` or `QLabel`, the object you create is actually a proxy to the C++ `QObject` or `QLabel`. The underlying C++ object is the actual `QObject` that is linked to the python proxy. Anyway it seems like you can't deepcopy a `QObject`(see [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-April/022896.html)). So find an other way of copying objects.
Also, are you sure you need a class defined in a class? I think that kind of things simply complicates code.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to inherit `QObject` (or `QWidget`), you must always call the super-class `__init__`:

```
class MyObject(QObject):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyObject, self).__init__(arguments to parent class)
        #other stuff here
```

You may also call the parent's class's `__init__` after some instructions, but you can't call `QObject` methods or use `QObject` attributes until you did so.

---

**Edit**:
In your case you are trying to `deepcopy` a `QWidget`, but this is **not** possible.
Python may be able to copy the *wrapper* of the `QWidget`, but the `QWidget` itself is a C++ object that python cannot handle with the default implementation of `copy.deepcopy`, hence whenever you call a method of the copied instance you get the `RuntimeError` because the underlying C++ object wasn't initialized properly.

The same is true for pickling these objects. Python is able to pickle the *wrapper*, not the C++ object itself, hence when unpickling the instance the result is a corrupted instance.

In order to support `deepcopy()` the `QWidget` class should implement the `__deepcopy__` method, but it does *not* do that.

If you want to copy widgets you'll have to implement by yourself all the mechanism by hand.

Comment: Please see the answer I wrote to Martijn Pieters above. I don't know how to share my code in a more clear way though...