# Dynamically add multiple QtGui items in python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, deep-copy

I Have the following problem:

I want to dynamically add multiple groups to a Qt Gui Layout in python. So: There are use cases where i need the group only once, and there are use cases where i need the group 4x.

Therefore i added a for loop and wanted to store the elements within an array of dicts:

```
self.swUiElements = []
for i in range(1,5):
  self.sw = dict()
  self.sw["groupBox"] = QtGui.QGroupBox(SWCopyMainWindow)
  self.sw["groupBox"].setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(915, 0))
  self.sw["groupBox"].setObjectName("gBSw_" + str(i))
  self.sw["groupBox"].setTitle("Test")
  self.sw["gridLayout"] = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.sw["groupBox"])
  self.sw["gridLayout"].setObjectName("gridLayout_" + str(i))
  self.sw["lbStatus"] = QtGui.QLabel(self.sw["groupBox"])
  self.sw["lbStatus"].setObjectName("lbStatus_" + str(i))
  self.sw["lbStatus"].setText("Status")
  self.swUiElements.append(copy.deepcopy(self.sw))
```

The Layout is initialised properly as i wanted.

I expected to use `self.swUiElements[0]["lbStatus"].text()` to work but it doesn't. As i learned from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280371/python-runtimeerror-super-class-init-of-s-was-never-called), this is because deepcopy won't work on Qt Objects.

Any other suggestions on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: just remove copy.deepcopy and it should just work

Comment: Yes. You're creating a **new** group of objects every time, so there is no point in copying them. You can also use just `sw` instead of `self.sw`. You should also be aware that every time `swUiElements` is re-created, the widgets it previously contained are **not** deleted, because their parents still hold a reference to them.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand the concept a bit better.
I realised i don`t have to access the fields directly (and if, i could find them by name via "findChild"), so the problem is solved for me